# constructor Of map with Class value

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, vector, constructor

```
class RadioManager {

    typedef MtmMap<double, Stations*> RadioMap;
    typedef RadioMap::Pair RadioPair;
    typedef RadioMap::iterator RadioMapIter;

    RadioMap radio;
    std::vector<Song> all_songs;
    unsigned long radio_clock;

    int findSong(const string& author, const string& name);
    void checkTime();
    void updateCurrent();

public:

~RadioManager();

    RadioManager() :
            radio(new Stations()), all_songs(), radio_clock(0) {
    }
```

Staions is a Base class that has inherited classes...

i get error in the Constructor...
Can anyone help me build one?
note that the Radio is A map that its values is class

Comment: what's `MtmMap`? is it `std::map` or `std::multimap`?

Comment: Your initializer list contains the initialization `radio(new Stations())`. The `radio` member variable is declared of type `MtmMap<double, Stations*>`, and you are trying to initialize it with a pointer to an object of type `Stations`. It couldn't possibly work.

Comment: andy prowl, I got ur point, MtmMap is a Map that the key is double and value is Stations* , that is a class....
Can you tell me how to initialize it right? i simply can't find the way to do so

Answer (score 0):

`RadioMap` is [map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), it's not a pointer, you don't need to call `new` to allocate Station, they are not even same type.

[std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)(or [std::multimap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)) and [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) have default constructor, they will be called in RadioManager

Try:

```
RadioManager() 
: radio(radio_clock(0)) 
{
}
```

Also better use smart pointers in STL containers instead of raw pointer, smart pointer will deallocate memory for you automatically.

```
typedef MtmMap<double, std::unique_ptr<Stations>> RadioMap;
```

Comment: sorry not working..i get this error : no matching function for call to âmtm::MtmMap<double, mtm::Stations*, std::less<double> >::MtmMap()â

Comment: no matching function for call to âmtm::MtmMap<double, mtm::Stations*, std::less<double> >::MtmMap()â

Comment: what exactly is `MtmMap`, can you try to replace it with std::map? see sample code: http://liveworkspace.org/code/3wzvpu$0